# For the summation $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{1*3*5*...(2n+1)}$ when performing the Ratio test, why is the $(-1)^{n+1}$ term removed?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the summation $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{1*3*5*...(2n+1)}$ when performing the Ratio test, why is the $(-1)^{n+1}$ term removed (this is what CalcChat shows).

I understand that $n!$ becomes $(n+1)!$ and $1*3*5*...(2n+1)$ becomes $1*3*5*...(2n+1)(2n+3)$ but I am having difficulty understanding why the -1 term disappears.

Comment: By the way, in symbols, $$1\times 3\times 5\times\cdots\times (2n+1) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k + 1).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test takes the limit of the absolute value of the ratio of consecutive terms. Since $|(-1)^{n+1}|=1$, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You use ratio test, so:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(n+1)!}{1*3*5*...(2n+1)*(2n+3)}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{1*3*5*...(2n+1)}}\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{(-1)*(n+1)}{2n+3}\right|=\frac{1}{2}$$

Note that in denominator you have $(-1)^{n+2}$ and in numerator $(-1)^{n+1}$.